# Should code segment edits be allowed?

Tags: feature-request, edits, code-block, whitespace

There's an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13812027/781965) which could benefit from the code being in a code segment, but I can't modify it because it's only whitespace characters. Even changing the "$3" to be `$3` is only two non-whitespace characters - on Stack Overflow the addition of those 4 spaces can make a big difference to otherwise small posts.

I am aware that small edits are discouraged, but in the linked answer for instance I couldn't find anything else that I would change. Moving things into code blocks just doesn't seem like a trivial edit, though - shouldn't the addition of whitespace which moves text into code segments be allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ability to perform relatively insignificant edits (< 6 non-whitespace characters) comes with reputation (2K). Currently your reputation is such that your edits must be approved and there are some restrictions on what the site will even allow you to submit before other users need to consider your edit.

For example, in [the answer in question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13812027/61305), I was able to make two edits independently - one adding the four spaces, and one adding ticks around the $3. Subsequently I added the suggestions Michael made to help illustrate that it is quite easy to make a minor edit more substantial by looking closer and not focusing on only one detail.

Comment: Yep. Jeff doesn't yet have 2k on Stack Overflow. Until he does, he can only suggest edits, and those are required to have at least six (non-whitespace, I believe) characters worth of changes.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelPetrotta, I've incorporated your additional information.

Comment: Ah, my apologies - I thought that that particular restriction carried through regardless of reputation.

Answer (score 4):

- Capitalize the first word of the first sentence.
- Add a period at the end of the last sentence.
- If you're considering wrapping the `$3` inside a code block, the `(\w+)` could also go inside a code block.

In my experience, there's always *something*, but then, I've got a weirdly good eye for that kind of thing.